# got production error after upgrade React-Intl, Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-intl

I know, some other questions already on this, but none of them discuss about production env, only testing component, my question is about production environment.

So, after upgrade react-intl i got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.
```

idk why, i try find solution about this, even on formatjs github issue still not fix this error

but if i don't upgrade this, `react-int` old version doesn't support with nodejs 16 or latest `react@17.x`, i need this latest `react` btw to support other packages too.

#### So my specs:

```
Node version: 16.14 (LTS)
NPM Version: 8.3.x
```

#### Packages:

```
react: 17.x
@mui/core: 5.x <<< i need this with latest react because for minimum requirements
react-intl: 5.x <<< so, i should upgrade this package too
```

i already set `IntlProvider`

#### App.js

```js
<IntlProvider locale={props.userLang || language} messages={messages}>
...
</IntlProvider>
```

##### EDIT :

so `react-intl` won't load if your components got errors, because it's wrapper component.
The solution is simple, `fix your errors on your components then react-intl will be execute properly`